# Azure Dev Spaces and Asp.Net Core Web Site returns Bad Gateway when not debugging in VS

Tags: traefik, azure-aks, azure-dev-spaces

This is what I did.

1. I setup a new AKS cluster (RBAC enabled)
2. I enabled Dev Spaces on it
3. I created a ASP.Net Core 2.2 Web Project
4. I started the project with the option to debug it in "Azure Dev Spaces" with "Public" selected. The project started fine and the web page was shown (http://default.webk8.54fqhtlhqv.weu.azds.io/)
5. I stoped the debugger

Now my web page returns "Bad Gateway" and the "devspaces-proxy" log returns this:

```
Accepted outer connection from 10.244.0.17:47390
Error opening inner connection for 10.244.0.17:47390 to 10.244.0.169:80: Connection refused 10.244.0.169:80
Reset outer connection from 10.244.0.17:47390
Disposed connections related to 10.244.0.17:47388
```

According to kubernetes web dashboard, my service has a endpoint 10.244.0.169 with ports http, 80, TCP and

Shouldn't I be able to access the page even after I stoped debugging or am I missing something here?